# Summing List Elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to do this question for this online coding course I'm part of, and one of the questions requires me to add together integers in a list. I've tried to find the answer (and visited a few other pages on this site), but I can't think of anything. Help please!

Here's my code so far:

```
total = 0
att = input("RSVPs: ")
att = att.split(",")
for i in att:
  print(sum(iatt) for i in att)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is caused because you provide sum with an integer value (`iatt = int(i)`) when you should be providing it with the contents of the list which is split on `','`.

You have a couple of options for this. Either provide a comprehension to `sum` and cast every element to an `int` inside the comprehension:

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in att))
```

or, use a built-in like `map` which pretty much does the same thing:

```
print(sum(map(int,att)))
```

in both cases, `sum` expects something that can be iterated through and it handles the summing.

Of course, you could manually loop over the contents of `att`, adding `int(i)` to `total` as you go:

```
for i in att:
    total += int(i)
print(total)
```

Comment: `sum(int(i) for i in att)` would be considered most 'Pythonic'.